# Filling database with some data (Users, Invoices, etc...)

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, seeding

I would like to fill my database with some data to let frontend developers start working with my API. I don't want this data to go live in production and so, doesn't feel it falls into the category of "Seeded data". For me, seeded data is data that goes into production and needs to be in the database before my application starts. For example, list of countries, etc.

In my case, I would like to add some users, some invoices linked to the users, some products, etc. And would be nice if this is done when doing thte deployment when we are in development stage.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create DataInitializer class to seed all needed data if environment is set to "Development".

E.g. creating user:

```
    public static class IdentityDataInitializer
{
    private static void SeedUsers(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        if (userManager.FindByNameAsync("Admin").Result == null)
        {
            ApplicationUser admin = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = "Admin",
                Email = "Admin@admin.com",
                RegistrationDate = DateTime.Now
            };

            string password = "Admin1";

            var result = userManager.CreateAsync(admin, password);

            if (result.Result.Succeeded)
            {
                userManager.AddToRoleAsync(admin, "Admin").Wait();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once all methods will be ready, just add this to your Startup.cs:

```
        public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app,
        IWebHostEnvironment env,
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            IdentityDataInitializer.SeedDefaultData(userManager, roleManager);
        }

        //Some methods...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your startup class you will want to check based on the environment (if it's in development or not) and call the appropriate seed method.

The command to check that is.

```
if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
```

For this task I would create a separate project to do it where I would only seed the data. It all depends on your architecture.

Comment: When you say, you would use a separate project, do you mean a asp.net core based project with EF to insert anything needed, am I right? This could be the best solution becase this way I decide when I want to inject the data.

Comment: @Notbad Correct. A simple project which belongs on the same solution. For some reason i know received notification for the comment :p